Selecting switching on brushless motor
this is my first question.
I've been researching design and calculus information about inverter stage on BLCD motors.
I found the following NEXPERIA APP NOTE which it's really helpful, but I don't agree with some calculus.
When it calculates voltage rms on motor for getting current rms that inverter's transistors should support it considers voltage rms up to vdd/2 affected by relationship on rectangular wave. VRMS = VDD/2 * sqrt(2/3) due to in trap control the phase only conducts two thirds.
Here it's explanation about vdd/2 and then they apply the rms factor on table below

Considering voltage waveform is like the following image, it shouldn't be rigth calculating voltage rms just like the next equation?



Am I missing something? I want to size rigth my switching devices.
I know the calculus doesn't change my VDS selection because anyway transistors should support at least the battery voltage, but I consider that flowing a lower rms current can help for selecting higher rds mosfet.
Thanks for your support!!

Which page says "VRMS = VDD/2 * sqrt(2/3) due to in trap control the phase only conducts two thirds."

The trapezoid is 50% duty cycle with Vmax for 2/6 periods and 2 ramps each 1/6 periods.
Vmax = Vdd
Vavg= 50% of Vdd
Vrms= 2/3 of Vdd
I did not find your reference to the equation.
I agree the correct equation is \$V_{rms}=\frac{2\cdot V_{DD}}{3}\$
and not \$ = \frac{V_{DD}}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\$
For a resistive load to gnd., each phase power is \$Pd=\frac{4}{9}\frac{V_{DD}}{R}\$
The plot from your link in question is unclear on how the 6-period cycle ends may look better as follows.

In your link they subtract a triangular wave {min-max injection} to reduce 3rd harmonics in an interesting web simulation.
A triangle wave from 0 to Vdd has a rms value of \$V_{rms}=\frac{V_{DD}}{\sqrt{3}}\$~57.73% Vdd.
Without the Vdd/2 offset and just +/-{Vdd/2} triangle, the rms becomes   \$\frac{V_{DD}}{2\cdot \sqrt{3}}\$

ref

The app note consider the maximum amplitude voltage on the following section on page 6 of the PDF (It's the same as the web) for a PMSM motor.
The same equation it's used in BLCD case but using sqrt(2/3) instead.
I believe I can´t share an image in a comment. I will paste it on the question. Besides there's a table where are the final calculated values. I understand they use the same concept on both cases.
Thanks for your answer!
